# How to run dot net core application in detached mode using "dotnet run" command

Tags: .net, .net-core

when we run dot net core application in linux using `dotnet run` command we have following output on terminal 
[image]

Where it asks to press `'ctrl+c'` to end application.

I want to run this application in detached mode so that my terminal will not hold with output screen like shown in above pic.

Answer (score 15):

I have managed to do this using nohup command.

```
nohup dotnet ReportGenerator.Web.dll > dotnetcore.log &
```

Answer (score 1):

dotnet run is a way to run application from [dev enviroment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore2x). 
My guess is that you are trying to run application on some non-development enviroment (UAT or Production). 
You should be using [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x) to get assemblies for deployment.
There you can use [supervisor](https://til.secretgeek.net/linux/supervisor.html) to keep it running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I managed to do it using "nohup" command

Comment: Any suggestion for Windows without WSL?

Answer (score 0):

If any one who use windows,you can use this command to start a new cmd windows run dotnet server.

```
cmd.exe /c "start  ""my app"" powershell.exe -NoExit -Command  ""dotnet myapp"""`
```

---

If anyone else need another solution for run multiple dotnet project.

It is [tye](https://github.com/dotnet/tye)